# Application of the Portmanteau Theorem for weak convergence

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, weak-convergence

I've got the following sequence of functions
\begin{align*}
F^N=(X^N_t-X^N_s)\prod_{i=1}^{n}f_i(X^N_{s_i}).
\end{align*}
for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $(X_t^N)_t$ a stochastic process converging weakly to $X^*$ and $f_i$'s being continuous, bounded functions on $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. $f_i\in C_b(\mathbb{R})$. By the continuous mapping theorem $F^N$ converges weakly.

Now that I have weak convergence, shouldn't there immediatly follow
\begin{align*}
\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}[F^N]=\mathbb{E}[F^*],
\end{align*}
from the Portmanteau Theorem? The paper I got this from states that we need to make use of the boundedness and continuity of the $f_i's$ and I don't understand why this is necessary (although I see that it works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weak convergence does not give convergence of expectations (which may not even exist). On $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure let $f_n(x)=nI_{(0,\frac 1 n)}$. Then $f_n \to 0$ a,.s, hence weakly. But $Ef_n=1$ for all $n$. Portmanteau's Theorem is not useful in proving that expectations converge.

Comment: According to the Portmanteau Theorem, the expectation of a bounded, uniformly continuous function converges. So if $F^N$ was bounded, thus the identity on the image of $F^N$ is bounded too, shouldn't I get the result with that?

Comment: @LeoHö But you are trying to apply Portmanteau's Theorem to the identity function which is not bounded.

Comment: Doesn't it depend on $Id(F^N)$ and not any more on the identity on all real numbers? I guess thats my last question to this topic. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @LeoHö But then you have to know that the range of $F^{N}$ is bounded. So Portmanteau's Theorem alone is not sufficient to guarantee that the menas converge